# (OpenCV VC++) How to make a dropdown box to select available webcams by name?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

What is the easiest way to list all available webcams by name in a drop down box to select from a drop box box?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an opencv question.

Adding even a simple gui to a c++ app is going to be a lot of work.
See [Good C++ GUI library for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows?rq=1) for some suggestions.